# Android Studio maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } Corrupts java & kotlin files

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, maven, gradle

I have to use `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to use the in-app payment library.

But when I add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` to `repositories` in `build.gradle (module)`->`allprojects`, files `Java` and `Kotlin` get corrupted and give an error.

My code after adding `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` is as follows.

build.gradle (project):

```gradle
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.sazl.cardbank"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 12
        versionName "1.1.1"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.duanhong169:colorpicker:1.1.6'
    implementation "com.github.cafebazaar.Poolakey:poolakey:2.1.0"
}
```

build.gradle (module):

```gradle
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Warning: this repository is going to shut down soon
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**These are the errors:**

`java` file error:
[image: Java File Error]

`kotlin` file error:
[image: Kotlin File Error]